# Environment Variable Empty in Bash Script

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-linux-2

I have an EC2 instance that I am deploying on AWS.

I am using an Amazon Linux 2, and I am passing a user data to it as such:

```
userdata_file.write(
        f'''
        #!/bin/bash\n
        export PAGERDUTYAPIKEY='mykey'\n
        sudo yum install git -y\n
        chmod +x ./basic_test.sh \n
        echo $PAGERDUTYAPIKEY> /home/ec2-user/pagerdutyapikey1.txt\n
        sudo ./basic_test.sh
        '''.strip()
    )
```

basic_test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "s/enterpagerdutyapikey/${PAGERDUTYAPIKEY}/g" > path.txt
```

However, when i run it, in the `path.txt` it is echoing as such:

```
s/enterpagerdutyapikey//g
```

But when i ssh in the server and run the same bash script, it echos as such:

```
s/enterpagerdutyapikey/mykey/g
```

Any idea why the environment variable `$PAGERDUTYAPIKEY` is rendering empty when i run through the userdata ?

Comment: You aren't using `SENDGRIDAPIKEY` in `basic_test.sh`; you're using `PAGERDUTYAPIKEY`.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, i did a typo on stackoverflow. I updated my code. Apologies

Comment: Oh, `sudo` does not preserve arbitrary environment variables by default for security reasons.

Comment: Can you modify `./basic_test.sh`? Just have it read directly from /home/ec2-user/pagedutyapikey1.txt` instead of using the environment.

Comment: Crossposted to [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/q/1087815/453007).

Comment: @chepner dropping sudo worked! Thanks a lot man